# Corona SDK arrow to show direction of ball?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm new to programming, and I wonder if you can help me out with this problem. I created a simple basketball game, where you pull back then release to fire the ball. I want to know how to use an image of an arrow to show the direction the ball will travel(It doesn't have to be the exact trajectory, just a straight arrow). Also, i want the yScale of the arrow to show how much linear impulse will be applied.Thanks in advance!

here is my function for shooting the ball

```
local function ballTouched(event)
if ball.x == 100 and ball.y == 100 then
    if event.phase == "began" then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(ball)
        arrow.alpha=1
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        physics.start()
        ball:applyLinearImpulse((event.xStart - event.x)/2, (event.yStart - event.y)/2, ball.x, ball.y)
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
        arrow.alpha=0
        man2.alpha=1
        man.alpha=0

    end
end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", ballTouched)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know the angle you are pulling back.  Just set the .rotation value of your arrow to the same angle.

```
arrow.rotation = aimAngle
```

To follow up to the comments below:

I'm assuming you are pulling the basketball back kind of like AngryBirds slingshot or you have to be touching and dragging somehow to have an angle.  You can use some simple angle math where you know the length of two sides of a right triangle and you can use the arctangent function to compute the angle.

```
local function angleBetween( srcX, srcY, dstX, dstY )
    local angle = ( math_deg( math_atan2( dstY-srcY, dstX-srcX ) )+90 )
    --if ( angle < 0 ) then angle = angle + 360 end
    return angle%360
end
```

where srcX and srcY would be the position (or start position of the basketball if you're dragging it) and dstX, dstY would be the event.x, event.y of where you let up during the ended phase.  The event table has a xStart and yStart members that kept track of where the touch event started, so maybe

```
 aimAngle = angleBetween(event.xStart, event.yStart, event.x, event.y)
```

You may need to play with some of these numbers to get them lined up the way you want them (i.e. you may need to add 180 or something)

Comment: Yes I understand, but how do you find the aimAngle?

Comment: I'm assuming you are pulling the basketball back kind of like AngryBirds slingshot or you have to be touching and dragging somehow to have an angle.  You can use some simple angle math where you know the length of two sides of a right triangle and you can use the arctangent function to compute the angle.